# Comsumir Web service em SOAP com grande volume de dados, TIME OUT

Tags: php, soap

Preciso pegar uma grande quantidade de dados de um web service em SOAP, porém dependendo da consulta o servidor não aguenta, já vi em alguns artigos, que isso pode ser resolvido mediante a compressão do xml ou envio em partes, mas não achei exemplos.

Tentei fazer um loop e encadear as requisições para cada registro, mas não funcionou, ele entende como se fosse somente uma requisição.

```
foreach ($this->vg['marcas'] as $key => $value) {

  $xmlr = new SimpleXMLElement('<CustumeSearch></CustumeSearch>');

  $paramsSoap = array(

    'categoria' => $tipoDados['nome'],

    'idMarca' => $key,

    'idModelo' => 0,

    'HashSeguranca' => 'xxxx'
  );


  // Looping responsavel por adicionar propriedade e valores ao XML exemplo (codigoAnuncio => 292)
foreach($paramsSoap as $key => $value) {

    $xmlr->addChild($key, $value);

  }

    $marcas = $this->vg['soap']->__soapCall(
        "RetornarVersoes" ,
        array($xmlr)
    ); ...
```

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O webservice é de fora ou é teu? Se for de fora não tens controlo sobre isso, no entanto em vez de teres um loop gigante, podes ter 2 ou 3 a começar de sitios diferentes, um no index= 0 outro no index = 10000 e fazes um pedido para cada um deles e no fim agregas as respostas num array ou assim.

Comment: Boa alternativa, vou tentar, porém não sei se vai dar certo pois toda vez que o índice do looping alterna eu reinicio a conexão SOAP, e mesmo assim não da certo.

Comment: Tens de ter uma "memória partilhada" e que seja fixa, variáveis globais que alteras, que estejam noutro ficheiro ou algo assim